# Changing Map Color based on parameter

Tags: tableau-api, shapefile

I'm working on a dashboard which shows me election results across election years.

I've created a parameter which has 3 values (strings) -  3 different election years. There are 3 categorical variables (winning party in each constituency) in my shape file which are associated with each of these parameters. I can drag the pill of these variables to color and get the resulting map.

I want to be able to choose an election year and have the color change accordingly in the map based on winners. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a variable EY which has election years and which goes into filter. 
Created a calculated field dependent on EY which changes based on election year and put this pill into color. So map color changes when I change EY now!

Answer (score 1):

why not use a filter for election year instead of a parameter, with it set as a single selection, this will let the user select just one year, and the map would be coloured accordingly.

Comment: Because election year isn't a variable, so I made a variable called election year which is associated with winning party with a IF clause.